# props are undefined inside componentwillmount but shown inside render in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When props data are passed as props then it's undefined inside componentWillMount but defined inside render.
What might be the problem???
**render**:

```
 public state: any = {
    authority: [],
    cid: "1",
    data: [],
    id: [],
    menuTitle: []
};
public componentWillMount() {
    var temp: any;
    let url: String = "http://localhost:9000/getFieldTitle/";
    fetch(url + this.state.cid + "")
        .then((response) => response.text()).then((value) => {
            let jsonObject = JSON.parse(value);
            for (let index in jsonObject) {
                for (let header in jsonObject[index]) {
                    temp = [];
                    if (header === "id") {
                        temp = this.state.id;
                        temp.push(jsonObject[index][header])
                        this.setState({ id: temp })
                    }
                    if (header === "menuTitle") {
                        temp = this.state.menuTitle;
                        temp.push(jsonObject[index][header])
                        this.setState({ menuTitle: temp })
                    }
                    if (header === "dataFormat") {
                        temp = this.state.data;
                        temp.push(jsonObject[index][header])
                        this.setState({ data: temp })
                    }
                    if (header === "authority") {
                        temp = this.state.authority;
                        temp.push(jsonObject[index][header])
                        this.setState({ authority: temp })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));

}
public render() {
    let row = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.authority.length; i++) {
        row.push(<FormSection
                key={i}
                id={this.state.id[i]}
                cid={this.state.cid[i]}
                menuTitle={this.state.menuTitle[i]}
                data={this.state.data[i]}
                />
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            {row}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**FormSection.tsx**:

```
<MenuSectionStructure data={this.props.data} check="check" />
```

**MenuSectionStructure.tsx**:

```
import * as React from "react";

export class MenuSectionStructure extends React.Component<any, any> {
    public state: any = {
        authority: [],
        dataType: [],
        fieldName: [],
    };

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    public componentWillMount() {
       console.log(this.props.data) // Gives undefined
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.data}</div>  //Gives value of this.props.data
        );
    }
```

### }

I have shown all data

Comment: Waiting for help anyone..... Thanks in advance....

Comment: What is the initial state of data in the render function? Is it an empty array?

Comment: yes it is empty array then i parsed value and pushed to it to render in loop

Comment: It's possible that the initial render is fired before the state is set, so `this.state.data[i]` is undefined. Could you post the main component with the render that you've specified?

Comment: I think that @MaxSindwani might be right, could you show how are you setting the state in the parent component?

Comment: ok i have edited question with additional code as you asked for.

Comment: Yep, Cesar's answer is right. As a side note, if you have control over the response, you may want to make it an array of objects since index doesn't seem to be used. Also, consider the spread operator if you want to create a new array with an appended value

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is definitely the one Max Sidwani commented. When you first load the parent component, you launch various setState in `componentDidMount`. Probably the header **authority** goes before the **dataFormat** one. This means that your component will re-render (and all its children) twice. The first time, authority.length will be an integer bigger than 0 and so the **render will loop and try to render FormSection components where the data prop will be undefined because the dataFormat header hasn't already been processed and the data state is still []**. Then, the data state is set and in the second re-render the data is not undefined. You can't watch two renders because the first one renders nothing and the second one happens inmediately after, but since you are using setState twice, render is being called twice (the first time with authority set and the second with data set). You can probably check this out with:

```
public componentWillUpdate() {
       console.log(this.props.data) // Not undefined
    }
```

in the `MenuSectionStructure` component.

You can solve it by **setting both states at the same setState** at the initial fetch or checking if data is not empty in the render.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the answer by sending the whole data as a single props and then parsing at the lowest component so that i could display all objects as a props in component as required. The problem was with sending multiple data as props and choosing one props as props length in loop which cause all problem since they all were all array and set state was hitting randomly causing the loop with unwanted sequence. However, sending the whole data as a single props and then looping inside came as a solution to my problem.
Thanks all for your contribution, which help me allot to visualize the reason of the scenario.